# How do I backup and restore a SQL Server database in C# using Entity Framework, use path on textbox in put

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, database-backups

I use C#, .net 4, Entity Framework and SQL Server 2012 in a project.

I have no familiarity with backup and restore from database by Entity Framework. Please help me to write restore and backup code in Entity Framework use path on textbox in put. thanks!

Comment: Entity Framework is for working with **entities** - loading data, saving it back etc. EF is **not** a SQL Server management library to backup databases and restore them again.

Comment: use pure ado.net. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142171/backup-sql-server-database-with-progress http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835553/how-to-backup-sql-database-programmatically-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Using of SQL **Server** you usually command **server** to make [backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) or [restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx) using path related to SQLServer process on server machine. EF has nothing to do with, although you can get path with textbox and send commands using database connection of your EF DbContext.

Relating to client, you can make some kind of backup, e.g. loading all data to DbContext and serialize it to file. But you cannot simply restore database from your deserialized DbContext due to absence of required metadata. If you really need to restore database from client data, you can create empty database using predefined SQL script or C# code generated during migration or [DatabaseInitializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696323(v=vs.113).aspx) and then fill this database using deserialized DbContext.